# Redirect /users/sign-in to Microsoft - GitLab

Tags: gitlab, azure-active-directory, gitlab-omnibus

I have a GitLab-CE installation where I have added Microsoft as login method. The "normal" username/password login is disabled.

Now I would like to be redirected directly to the Microsoft login page, as the GitLab login page is superfluous, as you only have the "Microsoft" button to choose from.

I wasn't able to find settings in the configuration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.